# How to convert negative seconds to hh:mm:ss in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm searching for a solution to convert negative seconds to `hh:mm:ss` format.
I want to display `-60` as `-00:01:00`.
This is what I have done

```js
var res = d.toString().split("-");
var currentValue = res[1];
var currentDuration = "-" + getDuration(currentValue);

function getDuration(d) {
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
    m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
    return h + ':' + m;
}
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: could you convert the absolute/positive value and add a negative sign in front of it?

Comment: Actually i am getting the negative value from the server. I'm trying to find a way to convert it without removing the leading minus, converting and adding minus sign.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Why do you not want to remove the minus sign ? What is the difference between converting -60 to minutes and 60 to minutes? 

There is nothing specific to a negative thing here, it's just how to convert seconds into hh:mm:ss format, and then just add a - in front of the output. 

You seem confused.

Comment: I know that way of conversion and that is what i have done. The thing is i'm wondering whether is there an option to convert it directly. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Input is integer and can be negative or positive:

```
function nSecToTime(s) { 
  let seconds = s
  s = Math.abs(s)

  let t = [0, 0, 0]
  let r = s % 3600

  t[0] = Math.floor(s / 3600)
  t[1] = Math.floor(r / 60)
  r = r % 60
  t[2] = r

  return (seconds < 0 ? "-" : "") + (t[0] < 10 ? "0" : "") + t[0]+":"+(t[1]<10?"0"+t[1]:t[1])+":"+(t[2]<10?"0"+t[2]:t[2])
}

nSecToTime(-58); // returns -00:00:58
nSecToTime(-8452); // returns -02:20:52
nSecToTime(2334); // returns 00:38:54
```

Comment: How does 58 seconds equals 00:01:09 ?